# Magento Unable to find item to save issue

Tags: extensions, magento-1.9.2.1

Weird issue.  We have our site on a local development server and everything works great.  We have the site on our live server environment as well and if we try to use any third party extension, we get the error Unable to find item to save when we try to add or modify.  We use GIT so the files are the exact same.  We dumped the live database, grabbed a copy of local, and replaced.  Same issue.  We've flushed cache and re-indexed.  Still get the error.

Live server is running nginx while local is running apache.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried creating a 1:1 replica of your live environment using a tool like Vagrant?

Comment: We figured it out.  Peer1 hosting had this in a magento_rewrite.conf file.  Once we commented this section out, everything works fine.

## SEO Rewrites ON except for install and admin handler, since rewrites are off by default
## If you have are using a different location for the 'admin' panel append it to the regex below
if ($request_uri ~* ^/index\.php(?!/(admin|install))) {
   rewrite /index\.php(.*)$ $1 permanent;
}

Comment: @JeremyMiller Please put your comment as an answer and tick it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

We figured it out. Peer1 hosting had this in a `magento_rewrite.conf` file. Once we commented this section out, everything works fine.

SEO Rewrites ON except for install and admin handler, since rewrites are off by default
If you have are using a different location for the 'admin' panel append it to the regex below

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^/index\.php(?!/(admin|install))) {
    rewrite /index\.php(.*)$ $1 permanent;
}
```